# Python: Matching columns based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

I am trying to reconcile two policy datasets on **Status**. Essentially I am trying to answer " Given a matching **PolicyNumber**, find all **PolicyNumbers** where **Status** does not match." Here is an example of the data (comma delimited):

```
policy1
PolicyNumber,Status,ExpirationDate
p0928999,Expired,01-02-2020
p092902,Cancelled,11-11-2020
p092902,Active, 10-02-2020
p089399, Active, 09-08-2020
p189128, Active, 12-20-2020
p77718, Active , 12-11-2020




policy2
PolicyNumber, Status, ExpirationDate
p0928999,Non-Renewal, 01-02-2020
p092902, Active , 10-02-2020
p089399,Non-Renewal, 09-08-2020
p889129, Cancelled, 02-01-2016
p77718, Renewed , 12-11-2020
p02902, Cancelled, 11-11-2020
p8383, Cancel Notice, 12-22-2020
p189128, Cancelled, 12-20-2020
```

A **Non-Renewal** status for *policy2* could equate to either a **Expired** *policy1* status or an **Active** *policy1* status depending on the expiration date:

- If a **Non-Renewal** in table *policy2* has an expiration date past
  the current date (07-20-2020) then it should equate to an **Active**
  status in *policy1*.
- If a **Non-Renewal** in table *policy2* has an expiration date prior
  to today (07-20-2020) then it should equate to an **Expired** status
  in *policy1*.

A **Renewed** or **Renewal** or **Non-Renew Requested in *policy2* status should equate to an **Active** policy status in *policy1*.

There may be duplicates in *policy1* table and if there are, I need to match the **Status** from *policy2* table to the latest expiration **PolicyNumber** policy in *policy1*. Ultimately I need to find any **PolicyNumbers** that don't have matching statuses based on the conditions specified.

A **Cancel Notice** status in policy2 should equate to **Active** in *policy1*.

So in this example p189128 has a **Status** of **Active** for *policy1* and **Cancelled** in *policy2*. This would be the only non-matching example. The output should be:

```
PolicyNumber
p189128
```

If there is a **PolicyNumber** that is not matched in both datasets (such as p189128,p02902,p8383) then it should be excluded from the matching process.

Here's my effort in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
cancel = pd.read_csv('policy1.csv')
policy = pd.read_csv('policy2.csv')

if (policy1["PolicyNumber"]==policy2["PolicyNumber"]):
    if (policy2["Status"]=="Non-Renewed"):
        if (pd.to_datetime(cancel["ExpirationDate"])>today()):
            cancel["Status"]="Active"
        else:
            cancel["Status"]="Expired"
    elif(policy2["Status"]=="Cancel Notice"):
        policy2["Status"]="Active"
    elif(policy2["Status"]=="Renewed"):
        policy2["Status"]="Active"
    elif(policy2["Status"]=="Renewal"):
        policy2["Status"]="Active"
    elif(policy2["Status"]=="Non-Renew Requested"):
        policy2["Status"]="Active"
    elif(policy2["Status"]=="Active"):
        policy2["Status"]="Active"
    elif(policy2["Status"]=="Cancelled"):
        policy2["Status"]="Cancelled"
    for i in policy2:
        if policy2["Status"] != policy1["Status"]:
            print(policy2["PolicyNumber"])
        else:
            pass
else:
    pass
```

When run I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

EDIT: Here is an example of me trying to make it work with np.select given the feedback I've gotten:

```
conditions =[(policy2['Status'] == 'Active'), 
             (policy2['Status']=='Cancel Notice'),
            (policy2['Status'])=='Cancelled'), 
             (policy2['Status'])=='Renewed'),
            (policy2['Status'])=='Non-Renewed')& (policy2['ExpirationDate'])>today()), 
             (policy2['Status'])=='Non-Renewed')& (policy2['ExpirationDate'])<today()),
             (policy2['Status'])=='Renewal'),
            (policy2['Status'])=='Non-Renew Requested')]
choices = ['Active','Cancelled','Cancelled','Active','Active','Expired','Active','Active']
policy2['Status'] = np.select(conditions,choice,default='Active')
for index, row in policy2.iterrows():
    np.where(policy2['PolicyNumber']==policy1['PolicyNumber'], np.where(policy2['Status']==policy1['Status'],pass,print(policy2["PolicyNumber"]) pass)
```

Comment: You don't use if else with pandas. You should read up on how to apply [if statements in pandas](https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use pandas like SQL - join the datasets together and then work the result out from the joined table.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
cancel = pd.DataFrame([[1234,None], [1235, "Cancelled"], [1255, None],[1278,"Cancelled"],[1539,'Cancelled']], columns=['policyid', 'status'])
```

Cancel is this df

```
policyid    status
0   1234    None
1   1235    Cancelled
2   1255    None
3   1278    Cancelled
4   1539    Cancelled
```

Policy is this df

```
policy = pd.DataFrame([[1234, "non-renewed"], [22335, "active"], [1255, "non-renewed"]],
                       columns=['policyid', 'status'])

policyid    status
0   1234    non-renewed
1   22335   active
2   1255    non-renewed
```

Set the indexes of each dataframe to policyid and join them together. Keep all of the rows in the cancel dataframe by using a left join.

```
cancel.set_index('policyid', inplace=True)
policy.set_index('policyid', inplace=True)
cancel = cancel.join(policy, rsuffix='_new', how='left')
```

Then fill the null values in cancel with the new status values in status_new (copied from the policy dataframe).

```
cancel['status'] = cancel['status'].fillna(cancel['status_new'])
cancel

    status  status_new
policyid        
1234    non-renewed non-renewed
1235    Cancelled   NaN
1255    non-renewed non-renewed
1278    Cancelled   NaN
1539    Cancelled   NaN
```

Now drop the status_new column.

```
cancel.drop(columns=['status_new'], inplace=True)
```